# What do i need to do after making an api call using refit

Tags: c#, .net, api, refit

I'm learning a little more about Restful in C# .NET but I'm having some problems when I call an API.
I had done a similar project before and it worked, but using the same template for this specific API is no longer working.

The idea is to consult an API (https://pokeapi.co) and check if the typed pokemon exists, maybe print its abilities or something along those lines, but when I make my call, the console returns "An error occurred deserializing the response. "

My code is quite simple, I split it into 3 parts:

Pokeresponse.cs

```cs
namespace Pokedex
{
    public class PokeResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("pokemon")]
        public string Pokemon { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
namespace Pokedex
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task  Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var pokemonClient = RestService.For<IPokeApiService>("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2");
                Console.WriteLine("Informe o pokemon");
                string informedPokemon = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

                Console.WriteLine($"Consultando informacoes do pokemon {informedPokemon}");
                var poke =await pokemonClient.GetAddressAsync(informedPokemon);
                Console.WriteLine($"\nAbilities:{poke.Id} ");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An Error occurred when searching for the pokemon"+ e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

IPokeApiService

```cs
namespace Pokedex
{
    public interface IPokeApiService
    {
        [Refit.Get("/pokemon/{pokemon}")]
        Task<PokeResponse> GetAddressAsync(string pokemon);
    }
}
```

could anyone give any tips on how to proceed? I tried to debug it but didn't get much progress.

Comment: did the answer below help you?

Comment: Sorry, i thought i answered you yesterday, but now i cant see my comment. I guess i didn't submit it. 
Anyway, your answer helped me, thanks.

Comment: Well, if you know how the system works, than you can understand this response that is given to me when i give the feedback: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 125 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the JSON response from [docs](https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon-section) you can see that there is no `Pokemon` field(so rename it to `Name`), also Id should be `int`(that was the real cause of exception)

Result:

```cs
public class PokeResponse
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```